# How do I extract UK county name matches from string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a list of UK county names and 8397 job titles which may contain those county names. I am able to find whether those matches are True or False or filter to rows where a string match was found.

However, I'd like to exract the match to another column when found but not sure how to do this. E.g. If a match to Surrey from ukcounties is found in UK['Title'] then extract Surrey to another column.

Thanks!!

```
ukcounties = ['Somerset', 'Staffordshire', 'Suffolk', 'Surrey']

UK['Title'] = 
['Relief Chef de Partie  Croydon  Surrey  Live in', 
'Pastry Chef Baker  artisan bakery  Suffolk Coast']

UK.Title.apply(lambda sentence: any(word in sentence for word in ukcounties))

Output:
9        False
12       False
13        True
26       False
27       False
         ...  
55157    False
55158    False
55159     True
55161     True
55165    False
Name: Title, Length: 8397, dtype: bool

UK[UK.Title.str.contains('|'.join(ukcounties))]
Output: 1003 rows × 12 columns
```

Comment: Do you mean to extract the counties, `UK['Title'].str.extract(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(ukcounties)))`?

Comment: Yep trying to extract the counties. I tried this code and got blank rows for some reason

Comment: `UK['Title'].str.extract(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(ukcounties)))` (if `UK` is a dataframe) shows `0   Surrey
1  Suffolk`

Comment: thanks! I restarted kernel and it works. Might of had some redundant code in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
UK['Title'].str.extract(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(ukcounties)))
```

Pandas test:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> UK = {'Title': ['Relief Chef de Partie  Croydon  Surrey  Live in', 
'Pastry Chef Baker  artisan bakery  Suffolk Coast']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(UK)
>>> ukcounties = ['Somerset', 'Staffordshire', 'Suffolk', 'Surrey']
>>> df['Title'].str.extract(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(ukcounties)))
#             0
#    0   Surrey
#    1  Suffolk
```

The `r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(ukcounties))` will form a regex like `\b(Somerset|Staffordshire|Suffolk|Surrey)\b` where

- `\b`  - a word boundary
- `(Somerset|Staffordshire|Suffolk|Surrey)` - Group 1: any of the words inside parentheses (`|` is an alternation operator)
- `\b`  - a word boundary